# Outlook Interop fails after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: .net, outlook, interop

I have a .net client program which sends emails using Interop for Outlook. This works fine on thousands of PCs on all versions of Windows. But following upgrades to Windows 10 a very small number of clients fail on sending an email with the message 'sendSystem.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005). Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed etc.'. 
nSomething has obviously happened with the upgrade to Windows 10. The Interop interface to Word continues to work normally. I suspect a permissions issue but cannot find any guidance on this. Any comments are very welcome.

Comment: It is a very nondescript error, your program tried to start Outlook.exe but that failed, the operating system could not get the process running.  This is an IT staff problem, they need to find out what is wrong with the user's machine.  They need to check if Outlook can be started at all, look at Task Manager's Processes tab to ensure that it hasn't been started 50-odd times before with none of them exiting, verify that the kernel memory pool isn't exhausted and look in the Application log for a possibly better error message.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response Hans.  Of course you are correct, it is an IT support issue rather than a program development problem. I was hoping that someone would have seen and solved this issue previously.

Comment: It is a laundry list of possible reasons.  You'll of course never figure out which one it is long-distance.  Neither can we.